# Javascript Couldn't understand a trick variable "hoisting": why it's NaN value?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, hoisting

I tried JavaScript to understand its hoisting strategy, but got more confused:

```
function f(i){this.i+=i}
i=2
f(3)
console.log(i)
```

It outputs

```
5
```

(1) This is what my expected. Then I tried to relocalte "i=2" statement:

```
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
console.log(i)
i=2
```

It outputs

```
NaN
```

(2) Why is that? I expected because "i" is hoisted to the front of the whole program, why it prints "NaN"? One possible answer is, the program is refactored by compiler to be:

```
var i
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
console.log(i)
i=2
```

(3) So when "console.log(i)", i has not be assigned any value, so it's "NaN"--->But I tried the program below:

```
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
i=2
console.log(i)
```

If the above explanation was correct, I expect this should also output "NaN". But in fact, it outputs

```
2
```

This is even more weird. Did "hoisting" worked at all in this case?

(4) More interestingly, if I change the program to be:

```
var i
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
console.log(i)
i=2
```

Then it outputs

```
undefined
```

Why is that?

(5) And for the program:

```
var i
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
i=2
console.log(i)
```

It again, outputs

```
2
```

Could you explain the above observations, as it really comes out of my understanding of what "hoisting" is?

Comment: In 3) and 5) you define i = 2 right before you do console.log(i) which is why it shows as 2.

Comment: It appears you're conflating "hoisting" with "context" and "scope".

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you never actually used the parameter `i` in the function `f(i)`.  `this.i` will refer to whatever object the function was called on, but `i` would refer to the parameter.  These are not necessarily the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very important thing to remember is that Javascript will only hoist function declarations, not when you call a function.

```
function f(i) { ... } //will be hoisted
f(2); //won't be hoisted
```

Moving on...

> I tried to relocalte "i=2" statement...It outputs `NaN`...Why is that? I expected because "i" is hoisted to the front of the whole program, why it prints "NaN"?

```
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3) //the function executes i = undefined+3, which is NaN
console.log(i) //i is logged, which is currently NaN
i=2 //i has the value of 2 assigned to it
```

*This outputs `NaN` because when a variable which is `undefined` is treated like a `Number`, it becomes `NaN`.*

> I expect this should also output "NaN". But in fact, it outputs `2`
>   This is even more weird. Did "hoisting" worked at all in this case?

```
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3) //the function executes i = undefined+3, which is NaN
i=2 //i has the value of 2 assigned to it
console.log(i) //i is logged, which is currently 2
```

*This outputs `2` because `i` is assigned the value of `2` just before `i` is logged.*

> ...it outputs `undefined` Why is that?

```
var i //i is undefined
function f(i){this.i+=i} //f is hoisted and is line 1
f(3) //the function assigns (undefined + 3) to a variable which is never referenced
console.log(i) //i is logged, which is currently undefined
i=2 //i has the value of 2 assigned to it
```

*This outputs `undefined` because `i` never had a value assigned to it before it was logged.*

> It again, outputs `2`

```
var i //i is undefined
function f(i){this.i+=i} //f is hoisted and is line 1
f(3) //the function assigns (undefined + 3) to a variable which is never referenced
i=2 //i has the value of 2 assigned to it
console.log(i) //i is logged, which is currently 2
```

*This outputs `2` because `i` is assigned the value of `2` just before `i` is logged.*

Answer (score 4):

As [@zzzzBov has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614811/javascript-couldnt-understand-a-trick-variable-hoisting-why-its-nan-value/38615042#comment64616298_38614811), this has nothing to do with hoisting, and everything to do with *context* and *scope*, specifically in a non-strict mode environment.

```js
function f(i){this.i+=i}
i=2
f(3)
console.log(i)
```

`i=2` is the equivalent of `window.i=2`. Since this is in non-strict mode, `this` is `window`, so `this.i+=i` is equivalent to `window.i+=i`, where the right-hand `i` is supplied from the function argument. So that should explain the output of `5`.

```js
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
console.log(i)
i=2
```

The only difference here is that `i=2` is executed *after* `this.i+=i`. Adding a number to an undeclared variable results in `NaN` as expected.

```js
var i
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
console.log(i)
i=2
```

Here, `var i` is attached to the `window` scope because this is in non-strict mode, so `this.i+=i` is adding a number to a declared, but uninitialized value, `window.i`, which still results in `NaN`.

```js
var i
function f(i){this.i+=i}
f(3)
i=2
console.log(i)
```

Here, hopefully is pretty obvious. `i=2` will overwrite whatever happened before (which in this case was `isNaN(i)===true`.

Any questions? Class dismissed.

Comment: That "Run code snippet" stuff is amazing! What did you do to embed that here? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Paurian http://i.stack.imgur.com/LWzth.png click the highlighted button when answering to add what's called a "stack snippet"

Answer (score 0):

Just because i is defined, doesn't mean it has a datatype. In JavaScript there are only a few set datatypes, Number being one of them.

Without a prior assignment, there is no way for the function to know if you are working with a number or a string from the "overloaded" plus operand.

With hoisting, it doesn't preclude the flow of the instructions, just where variable declaration takes place. If a variable isn't *initializied*, it remains an untyped variable until the first assignment.

Comment: _"there is no way for the function to know if you are working with a number or a string"_ - this has nothing to do with why it's `NaN`. A function doesn't have to "know" anything. JavaScript just defines the addition of `undefined` with a numeric type as `NaN`, end of story. There is no "overloading" in JavaScript either, only a clearly defined set of rules for implicit typecasting whenever objects of different types are added together. And a JavaScript variable _does_ have a type when it is declared and not initialized, it is `undefined`. `typeof undefined === "undefined"`.

Comment: I realize "overload" was a bad term (I tried quoting it to make that clear, but a better term should have been used). I wasn't sure how to describe that the plus operand isn't a unitasker and can work with strings and numbers. Thanks for clarifying.